# How to fix issue that AnimatedContainer with height 0 is still visible in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am implementing "scroll down to hide, scroll up to show" functionality for one widget that is rendered just before a list.

I did create this widget `ScrollToHide`

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class ScrollToHide extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>> childKey;
  final Widget child;
  final ScrollController controller;
  final double placeholderHeight;
  final Duration duration;

  const ScrollToHide(
      {Key? key,
      required this.childKey,
      required this.child,
      required this.controller,
      required this.placeholderHeight,
      this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 200)})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScrollToHideState createState() => _ScrollToHideState();
}

class _ScrollToHideState extends State<ScrollToHide> {
  bool _isVisible = true;
  Timer? _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 5),
      (Timer timer) {
        final size = _getChildSize();
        if (size.height == 0) {
          return;
        } else {
          _timer?.cancel();
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
    );
    widget.controller.addListener(_listen);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    widget.controller.removeListener(_listen);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _listen() {
    final direction = widget.controller.position.userScrollDirection;

    if (direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      _hide();
    } else if (direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
      _show();
    }
  }

  void _show() {
    if (!_isVisible) {
      setState(() {
        _isVisible = true;
      });
    }
  }

  void _hide() {
    if (_isVisible) {
      setState(() {
        _isVisible = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = _getChildSize().height;
    height = height == 0 ? widget.placeholderHeight : height;
    return AnimatedContainer(
      child: Wrap(children: [widget.child]),
      duration: widget.duration,
      height: _isVisible ? height : 0,
    );
  }

  Size _getChildSize() {
    final RenderBox? renderBox =
        widget.childKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    if (renderBox == null) {
      return const Size(0, 0);
    }
    return renderBox.size;
  }
}
```

and am using it inside my page like below (simplified and removed confidential code)

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/blocks/posts_bloc.dart';
import 'package:app/di/injector.dart';
import 'package:app/dtos/post.dart';
import 'package:app/l10n/l10n.dart';
import 'package:app/ui/common/paginated_list.dart';
import 'package:app/ui/common/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:app/ui/common/scroll_to_hide_widget.dart';
import 'package:app/ui/widgets/loading_indicator.dart';
import 'package:app/utils/paginated_state.dart';

class PostsTabView extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostsTabView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PostsTabViewState createState() => _PostsTabViewState();
}

class _PostsTabViewState extends State<PostsTabView> {
  final _dataBloc = inject<PostsBloc>();

  late ScrollController _scrollController;
  final GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>> _createPostAndFiltersKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dataBloc.fetch();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          ScrollToHide(
            controller: _scrollController,
            childKey: _createPostAndFiltersKey,
            placeholderHeight: 152,
            child: Card(
              key: _createPostAndFiltersKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
                    child: RoundedButton(
                      text: S.of(context).create_post_btn,
                      color: const Color(0xff5cb85c),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(context, CreatePostPage.route());
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  _filtersView(),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(child: _postsView()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _filtersView() {
    return StreamBuilder<PostQueryFilters>(
        stream: _dataBloc.filtersStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final filters = snapshot.data ?? PostQueryFilters.initial();

          return SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Wrap(
              spacing: 4,
              children: [
                Text('filter-1'),
                Text('filter-2'),
                Text('etc not important for the example'),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget _postsView() {
    return StreamBuilder<PaginatedState<Post>?>(
        stream: _dataBloc.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final data = snapshot.data!;
            return PaginatedList<Post>(
              scrollController: _scrollController,
              useOuterScroll: true,
              paginatedState: data,
              networkState: _dataBloc.networkStream,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return _buildPost(
                  index,
                  data.data[index],
                );
              },
              onEndReached: _onEndReached,
              retryCallback: _retryFetch,
            );
          }

          return NetworkStateItem(
            _dataBloc.networkStream,
            _retryFetch,
            errorMessage: S.of(context).internal_server_error,
          );
        });
  }

  Widget _buildPost(int index, Post post) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('just for example $post.title')
      ],
    );
  }

  _onEndReached() {
    _dataBloc.fetch();
  }

  _retryFetch() {
    _dataBloc.fetch(force: true);
  }
}
```

When I scroll down (reverse) it really hides with nice animation of 200ms but if I keep scrolling I still see partially small parts of the "hidden, height 0" widget. It is like a glitch of sorts, I keep scrolling down it shows it hides a little, then when I scroll up is shown again as expected.